# What's the difference between てかなわない and てたまらない？？

Tags: grammar

To my understanding てたまらない and てかなわない both mean "can't stand/unable to". However, I believe that てかなわない can't be used with adjectives of feeling, while てたまらない can. My question is how can I distinguish between them? It also seems really similar to 堪えない/耐えない so I got a little confused.